# How can I decompile an exe file I made with Pyinstaller?

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

I made a .py file and was looking how to convert it into an .exe file. I found pyinstaller and while messing around with it I was able to create a basic exe file with pyinstaller. The problem is that I didnt have a copy of my .py file as backup because I'm a beginner and now I can't look at my source code. Is there a way for me to decompile the pyinstaller files to attempt to recover some of my code?

My .py file was created in python 3.8 if that is relevant

Comment: Running pyinstaller to create an exe file does not remove your original source files from your computer, and being a beginner does not make that happen either.

Comment: well the .py file is now blank and i don't know what caused it